# Use Sugar ORM with Flickr API

Tags: android, sqlite, flickr, sugarorm

I want to use SugarORM with Flickr API.
We need to `extends` class with `SugarRecord<ClassNAME>` but flickr api provide builtin classes for accessing photos and gallery etc classes we cannot extends them with `SugarRecord<ClassNAME>`. so how we use sugarORM in such situation!

sorry for bad english!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'flickr api' do you mean https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/? Or their REST api?

Comment: this one 'com.googlecode.flickrj-android:flickrj-android:2.1.0', not REST api

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats the drastic downside of SugarORM. If you *have* to use the combination of SugarORM and the FlickrJ Android library, your options are:

1. Change the source of FlickrJ so all the classes that you want to use extend `SugarRecord` or
2. Write own versions of all needed classes, let them extend `SugarRecord` and write some type of converter between the original classes and your own classes (cumbersome).